# Symbol for set operation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'd like to know if there is already a symbol (notation) for grouping similar elements in a set. For example, suppose
$$
S=\{\underbrace{a_1, a_2, \cdots}_{G_1}, \underbrace{b_1,b_2, \cdots}_{G_2},\cdots\}=\{G_1, G_2\}
$$
I want to use $G_1$ to represent $a_1, a_2, \cdots$ and $G_2$ to represent $b_1, b_2, \cdots$. So basically $G_1$ is the collection of $a_i$ but without curly bracket. Is there a symbol or notation for such operation?

Comment: I am a set theorist and am telling you it is not, and it doesn't. Please don't add the tag again.

Comment: Let me be more explicit. There is no "collection without the curly brackets". Such a thing does not exist as an object. It is not interesting and people do not use it. It may be that notationally sometimes you want to write just, say, $\mathbf a $ rather than $ a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n $. That's fine. It is stuff people do all the time, and there is no standard convention. But $\mathbf a $, or whatever, is not an object. It is just notation. If you want an actual object, you either look at sets, or tuples, or some such. But that is a different thing.

Comment: Any notation used for partitions or equivalence classes could be used.

Comment: I think @AndrésE.Caicedo has the right idea, you could simply just label such elements as $\textbf{a}$. No reason for a completely new notation.

Comment: Ok, if no such symbol exists, we can always invent one as long as there are needs for this operation.

Comment: I recently came across the notion of a "bunch" which seems like what the OP is looking for: the "contents of a set without the container". It is an interesting idea mentioned on this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type) , referring to this article: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019081900715. The same author also presents the idea in this book: http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~hehner/aPToP/aPToP.pdf I think The idea is worth investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In programming this in known as a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) or [splat operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion). You could try something like this:

$$G = \{...G_1,\space ...G_2\}$$
$$G = \{*G_1, *G_2\}$$
$$G = \{{}^*G_1, {}^*G_2\}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm. What about the union symbol?

> Let $G_1 = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots \}$, $G_2 = \{b_1, b_2, \ldots \}$ and
>   $G = G_1 \cup G_2$.

If you have more than two sets, you could use double indexing:

> For each $i \in I$, let $G_i = \{a_{i,j} \mid j \in J_i\}$ and let $G = \bigcup_{i \in I} G_i$.

Comment: No, the point is that the $G_i $ are not sets.

Comment: @andrés-e-caicedo This is not clear at all from the statement of the question, especially since the OP states that $S$ is a set.

Comment: $S=\{G_1,G_2\} $ is stated explicitly in the question.

Comment: Close, what I need is $\{G_1\} = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots \}$.

Comment: @andrés-e-caicedo Sorry, I was totally confused. When you wrote that the $G_i$ are not sets, I thought you were referring to some set theoretic argument, like Russell's paradox.